# How to avoid internal calling function when running PHPUnit test? And how to set mock data for internal performance?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a class Receipt.php

```
<?php
namespace TDD;
class Receipt {
    private $user_id = 1;
    private $pending_amount;
    public function total(array $items = []){
    $items[] = $this->pending();
       return array_sum($items);
    }

    public function tax($amount,$tax){
        return $amount * $tax;
    }
    
    private function pending()
    {
        $sql = 'select pending_amount from Pending_transtions where user_id =' . $this->user_id . ' limit 1;';
        //$pending_amt = $this->mainDb->get_sql_row($sql);
        //$this->pending = $pending_amt['pending_amount'];  
        return $this->pending_amount = 45;
    }
    
    public function addTaxPending($tax){
        return $this->pending_amount * $tax;
    }
}?>
```

And in my PHPUnit file, ReceiptTest.php

```
<?php
namespace TDD\Test;
require(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'vendor'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'autoload.php';
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase; 
use TDD\Receipt; 


class ReceiptTest extends TestCase{
    public function setUp(): void {
        $this->Receipt = new Receipt();
    }
    public function tearDown(): void{
        unset($this->Receipt);
    }
    public function testTotal(){
        $input = [0,2,5,8];
        $output = $this->Receipt->total($input);
        $this->assertEquals(15,$output,"this is not valid");        
    }   

    public function testTax(){
        $inputAmount = 10.00;
        $inputTax =  0.10;
        $output = $this->Receipt->tax($inputAmount,$inputTax);
        $this->assertEquals(1.0,$output,"this tax expecting 1.0");      
    }   
}?>
```

**question:**

How to ignore internal calling function `pending()` because it fetches data from DB. At the same time I want to access the property of `$this->pending_amount`.

Here `Pending()` must be private function.

How can I achieve that? I am looking for your valuable solutions

Answer (score 2):

Proper solution is to replace your dependency (the one which is saved under `$this->mainDb` in your example) with a "mocked" one in your test case.

Here is an article from PHPUnit manual, which shows how to create mocks - https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/test-doubles.html#mock-objects

--

Speaking about ways of injection: your can either pass `$this->mainDb` instance via class constructor, or make so-called "seam" in form of public `setMainDb` method (which is not an elegant solution - I'd prefer to avoid it).

Another thing which I had to do sometimes, is to replace the value via Reflection: make private property accessible and set it inside of test to the value I need.

--

**Update:**

Based on given example, I think the easiest way to achieve desired result is:

1. Change test case's `setUp` to:

```php
  public function setUp(): void
  {
    $this->Receipt = new Receipt();

    $mainDbMock = new class() {
      public function get_sql_row() {
        return [
          "pending_amount" => 0
        ];
      }
    };

    $this->Receipt->setMainDb($mainDbMock);
  }
```

2. Add "seam"-method to your `Receipt` class:

```php
  public function setMainDb($mainDb)
  {
    $this->mainDb = $mainDb;
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide some example code?

Comment: @Siddharthaesunuri Ok, please see my update.

Comment: I have to access private property  $this->pending_amount in any cost at PHPUnit

Comment: If you'd like to set `$this->pending_amount` to some value (and in fact you're doing this via DB query) - then you're able to change the value returned by your `$mainDbMock`. If you'd like to "assert" it in PHPUnit (`assertEquals` etc) - then you either need to add "get" method to access it, or access it via Reflection: make the properly "public" in test and read it freely. But then my question is: why do you need to assert private property, returned by another component? (`$mainDB` in your case).

Comment: But here $this->pending_amount property need in all methods for some calculations

Comment: (I continue here). In case if you need to test if your SQL query is doing a right thing, then write a class with public method `findPendingAmount`, do all queries there and write a test for it. So in simple words: move `pending()` method away from `Receipt`, put it in `ReceiptRepository` and make it public. Don't be afraid to separate independent things from each other: each component should serve its own purpose. This is what unit testing is showing us almost immediately: your difficulties with private `pending()` method happened exactly because of this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to mock the dependency. The dependency in your case is the database. You need to replace access to the database with a mock that you can configure with known return values.

Take the time to read the [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/test-doubles.html#mock-objects) documentation on how to use mock objects.

### A basic example

Given a DB access class with a `get_sql_row` method that accepts an SQL string and returns some data structure, we don't need to fill in any code here in our example because we're going to mock the `get_sql_row` method and configure it to return known values for our test.

```
class MainDb
{
    public function get_sql_row(string $sql)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Our receipt class accepts a DB access object in the constructor and uses it to execute SQL e.g. the `pending` method executes SQL to get the pending amount (if any).

```
class Receipt
{
    public function __construct($mainDb)
    {
        $this->mainDb = $mainDb;
    }

    public function total(array $items = [])
    {
        $items[] = $this->pending();

        return array_sum($items);
    }

    private function pending()
    {
        $pendingAmount = $this->mainDb->get_sql_row('sql...');

        return $pendingAmount['pending_amount'];
    }
}
```

In the testcase setup method we create a mock of the DB access class and create the receipt object with the mocked database. The mock is then used in the tests to configure expectations, received arguments, and return values.

The `testTotalWithNoPendingAmount` test configures the DB mock to return 0 when `get_sql_row` is invoked. The `get_sql_row` is only expected to be called once and will fail otherwise. Configuring `get_sql_row` to return a known value allows us to test the behaviour of the receipt class without touching the DB.

Similarly, `testTotalWithPendingAmount` configures the DB mock `get_sql_row` to return a value other than 0 so that we can test behaviour of calculating the total when there is a pending amount.

```
final class ReceiptTest extends TestCase
{
    protected Receipt $receipt;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        // create a mock of the database access object
        $this->dbMock = $this->createMock(MainDb::class);

        // create receipt with mocked database
        $this->receipt = new Receipt($this->dbMock);
    }

    public function testTotalWithNoPendingAmount(): void
    {
        $this->dbMock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('get_sql_row')
            ->willReturn(['pending_amount' => 0]);

        $this->assertEquals(15, $this->receipt->total([0, 2, 5, 8]));
    }

    public function testTotalWithPendingAmount(): void
    {
        $this->dbMock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('get_sql_row')
            ->willReturn(['pending_amount' => 3]);

        $this->assertEquals(18, $this->receipt->total([0, 2, 5, 8]));
    }
}
```

Take the time to read the [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/test-doubles.html#mock-objects) documentation on using mock objects and understand how they work and how to use them in your testing.

Note also that your handling of SQL is potentially open to SQL injection. Please read about SQL injection.

Comment: My pending method must be Private method

Comment: That was a typo. The examples work fine when the pending method is private. We're mocking the db method that the pending method uses so it doesn't matter what visibility the pending method has.

Comment: I got it, 

Here I have another problem, Please check this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73384264/how-to-skip-internal-calling-function-in-phpunit-test